# What are scope functions in Dlang?

Tags: d, scoping

From https://github.com/MartinNowak/io/blob/master/src/std/io/package.d:

```
size_t write(const scope ubyte[] buf) scope;
```

What is the meaning of the second `scope` keyword?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It applies the `scope` qualifier to the hidden `this` parameter.

Generally speaking, any keyword after the function applies to `this`, but otherwise has the same result as if it was on any other parameter. For example, a `const` at the end means the `this` reference is `const`.